# Looking to Incorporate Version Control after the fact

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I'm doing a single developer Visual Studio solution and reached a point where I'd like to incorporate Versioning Control.  Several posts address this issue, but one problem I'm facing is a large merge.  I have a production copy of the solution and a beta copy.  They are NOT dramatically different, but they will require a number of interactions I suspect.  I'm using TortoiseSVN and have imported the production version.

Yes, I know I should have used Version Control from the start, but that is hind sight.  Would it be best practice to simply use the beta as a reference and work the interations from scratch.  Or should I branch off and import the beta separately, then attempt to merge the change.  Or is there another alternative I'm missing.

Thanks,
dgp

Answer (score 0):

well, I have experienced SVN in the past ... and I must say, **it's lovely** cause it's really easy to understand the concept, but **it's awful terrible** when things pass from the plain `commit`.

I'm currently using **GIT** (to host small code on GitHub) and **Mercurial (Hg)** (I use Kiln in the company - was recommended by myself so they can start using - and in BitBucket for personal use)

I have used SVN for more than a hole year and every time I need something from "the past" or to merge something, it was a nightmare, but the server/client concept was really a break deal and extremely easy to get it... but I found my self, over and over to do merging by hand :(

When GIT started to be hot, I was afraid to move as, dang! SVN was a pain, why should be different in a DVCS?

This videos rocked my world, [ [part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLLkJ2rngk0) [part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDJOb2wGLjY) ], only then I understood DVCS vs VCS and it was with this that I moved **COMPLETELY** to DVCS and never go back... proudly!

---

For your problem, I would install git (or hg), and then create a repository on the folder you have your current source with:

`git init` will tell your folder, "Hey, I'm a GIT Repo"

`git add .` let's add all files and folders to be tracked by git

`git commit -m "initial commit"` let's save all the hard work :)

So, now you have a tracked code, you can simple create a branch and overwrite all your files. YES, worry not, you don't need to have copies of your code in a folder called `branch` ;) no more copies! all is in the GIT database

then, after creating the branch, changed the files, added all files to be tracked on that branch and committed, **safely do a merge** :)

ohh, and you don't need a server connection to do all this, all you need is a computer with  GIT installed... no more connection dependencies! DVCS is cool or what?! :D

Comment: balexandre, thanks for the input and video link.  Dan York did a great job of explaining things.  It is insightful how he uses a version control system for much more than code development.  Being new to TortoiseSVN (and I may switch over to GitHub), I'm still not clear on the method of merging of the two different version.  I'm thinking I can perhaps have the software merge and find any conflicts.  I could then fix any conflicts by hand and let the system handle the rest.  Thoughts?

Comment: Yes you should, **but never with a VCS system** (SVN for example) as they track the files and not a change set (line changes) - *that's why merging in VCS is extremely painful* - choose a good DVCS (Git or Hg) and do some tests on 3 or 4 files prior to commit, that was the idea I tried to pass on my answer :)